# JWT Header algorithm: is "hs256" the same as "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256"

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm trying to sign a JWT using HS256. I'm using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` . When decoding the token using `jwt.io` I get *invalid signature* and I've noticed that my headers read:

```
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

rather than `{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}` as I expected.

Is this what's causing the invalid signature? Also any ideas on a fix? Please note that I need to include custom claims as well.

```
var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientsecret));
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);
```

Comment: the reason why your signature is considered invalid on jwt.io is usually due to the fact that you didn't paste the secret into the field under "verify signature" in the right column. `HS256` is the short name for `hmac-sha256`, but I don't know how to change it and if causes other problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i believe changing the fields on the right, changes the encoded string on the left, so will cause it to be verified inherently.

Comment: @that's true when the secret doesn't match the one used for signing (and then the verification is worthless). You need to first paste the secret and then paste the token on the left to see if the existing token can be verified with the given secret.

Comment: Ah right yes makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your JSON Web Token (JWT) as follows using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, which should set all fields correctly (`secret` is the key you use to sign your JWT):

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
  Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("sub", "customer") }),
  Issuer = "Who issued the token",
  Claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    ["email"] = Email, 
  },
  IssuedAt = now,
  NotBefore = now,
  Expires = now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
  SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var serializedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

`serializedToken` finally contains the serialized JWT.

Please note that the `SecurityTokenDescriptor`class is from the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens namespace of the [same NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/), not from System.IdentityModel.Tokens namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry i should have specified that i need custom claims such as email, is there anyway of integrating custom claims into your method? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the [tokenDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokendescriptor) has a `Claims` dictionary for custom claims (see my edited answer), as well as an `AdditionalHeaderClaims` dictionary if you want to extend the JWT header.

Comment: hi, thanks so much for your help - I'm still having an issue unfortunately. At line: var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor , i get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Am i missing something?

Comment: SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Claims =
                {
                    ["iss"] = clientid,
                    ["sub"] = "customer",
                    ["iat"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
                    ["jti"] = Jti,
                    ["email"] = Email
                },
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(clientsecretba), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

Comment: is this for asp.net core?

Comment: See my updated answer - the exception is because you need to set the dictionary. Also "iss" is the same as setting the "Issuer" property in my example, "sub" = "Subject" and "iat" = "IssuedAt". Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens is used by ASP.NET Core but not part of it.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That was the issu. This is the first time I've ever managed to get this working :)

Answer (score 2):

**SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature**

change

**SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256**

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to elaborate how this will solve the problem.